# How to add SKILL numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to put numbers like 1N4 type text in the box which will indicate that 1 person has 4 level skill . for example in row 16 , 1N1 means 1 person wth skill 1 , 1N3 means 1 person with skill3 and 1N4 means 1 person with skill 4 .

I need to fill `Skill` column by looking into XYT column data .

So far I do this manually can we add some formula to make this ?

[image]

After my attempt I am able to do this , but I need small help

I want to hide the values which has 0 in starting . How can I do that  ?

[image]

Comment: Start with right(B2,1) then think how to get multiple parts : perhaps find()...

Comment: Can you be more clear about the output and input: Do you start with '1N2' and you need this to be spilled on the right into numbers **or** do you start with these numbers and you need to get the text back? Best to include markdown sample data with expected results, currently I don't quite see correct results in your screenshot.

Comment: @JvdV Apologies , I need to fill Skill column by looking into the X YT  column. I have added new screenshot.

Comment: So there is a max of three potential values, X Y & T? Try to come up with some formula (no matter how bad) to make this on-topic and ready for debugging. It won't be too hard to help you out on this one.

Comment: It's still not clear at all to me what's needed. Rows 8, 9, 10 all have the same X, Y, T values, but "Skills" has different values. What are the *precise* inputs and outputs, with 100% accurate and complete examples? You also are asking how to fill the `Skill` column but I think you mean `Skills`. Be accurate.

Comment: @tenfour Please check the screenshot . I have updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways in doing this, here is one:

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,LET(X,SEQUENCE(4),Y,COUNTIF(B1:D1,X),FILTER(Y&"N"&X,Y)))
```

---

Or, if you want to do this in a single go for the entire range:

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=BYROW(B1:D5,LAMBDA(z,LET(X,SEQUENCE(4),Y,MMULT(--(z=X),{1,1,1}),TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTER(Y&"N"&X,Y)))))
```

Comment: Thank you . I don't understand , when I use your formula I see `#Name?`  in the cell

Comment: Microsoft 365 , excel version 2201 . Which version this formula will work  ?

Comment: @Yogus, it's in the updated answer. But note, if `REDUCE()` was not working for you, the 2nd formula using `BYROW()` might also not be available to you just yet. You'd still have to drag down the 1st option.

Comment: Could you please share the other Reduce formula pls .I need it too

Comment: Multiple ways of writing that one, for example: `=REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(4),LAMBDA(a,b,TEXTJOIN(" ",,a,SUBSTITUTE(b&"N"&COUNTIF(B1:D1,b),b&"N0",""))))` @Yogus

Comment: Thanks ! but this REDUCE() didn't worked in Office 2016 excel either

Comment: @yogus, offcourse not. It's a ms365 function

Comment: but none of the above solution worked in excel 2016  . Pls help

Comment: @Yogus, appliant to my sample data in the screenshot, you could use `=IF(COUNTIF(B1:D1,1),COUNTIF(B1:D1,1)&"N1 ","")&IF(COUNTIF(B1:D1,2),COUNTIF(B1:D1,2)&"N2 ","")&IF(COUNTIF(B1:D1,3),COUNTIF(B1:D1,3)&"N3 ","")&IF(COUNTIF(B1:D1,4),COUNTIF(B1:D1,4)&"N4 ","")`, but note how Excel 2016 is such a barebones Excel version.